# Exporting d3 __data__ property with jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, scatter-plot, jsdom

I am adopting the code for the brushable scatter matrix using d3 and jsdom on server side to generate the SVG.

SVG is perfectly generated.

However in the node script I am also binding data to some svg elements that is later used on the client side for mouse events interaction.

Here is (the well known) snapshot:

```
var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
    .data(cross(traits, traits))
    ...
```

At the end I am just saving the generated HTML to a file using

```
jsdom.window.document.querySelector("html").outerHTML;
```

which doesnt actually save `__data__` property of the `.cell` elements.

[image: cell data client side]

Of course any method invocation that uses these values on client side fails with **undefined**.

On the server side on debug I can perfectly see `__data__` property assigned to each of my svg elements.

[image: debug mode server side]

**I am just wondering is there any way to tell jsdom to export/save even the properties stored during generation or it can be done later only on client side???**

Comment: I think this might be easier to answer if you could give us a hint on what you are trying to achieve with this. How much data are we talking about? Also, an excerpt of your data could be useful.

Comment: Hi @altocumulus, as i mentioned, regardless of the data (content, volume etc.) i just want to export the HTML containing __data__ property previosly visible and accessible on the server side in the jsdom object. Reason for why I am doing the .svg generation on server side is not relevant atm. Anyway the __data__ property created with the d3 contains simple data as cell coordinates for example.

Comment: How about dumping the data inside a javascript variable inside a `script`, next to the SVG export?

Comment: @Mehdi that is one of the options if nothing can be done with jsdom to "save" that data into the element's property.